# Print multiple plot functions from same parent function

Tags: r, function, plot

I would like to use a parent function that creates two additional plot functions, and when I call the parent function, I would like both plots to be returned. Ideally, I would like the plots to be returned as two separate objects instead of using something like `par()` to combine the two plots into a single image.

The code below only returns the second of the two plots.

```
test_fx <- function() {
  
  # Define the first plot
  plot1_fx <- function() {
    plot(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(3,4,5), type='l')
    abline(v=1.5, col="red", lwd=5)
  }
  
  # Define the second plot
  plot2_fx <- function() {
    plot(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(5,4,3), type='l')
    abline(v=2.5, col="blue", lwd=5)
  }

  # Return the plots
  plot1_fx()
  plot2_fx()

}


# Call the main function
test_fx()
```

Comment: If you're in interactive console, setting `windows.options(record = TRUE)` will save each plot in the historial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base function `plot` does not return a useful value, it returns `NULL`. To return both plots, have the function (`test_fx`) return functions. `test_fx` is a functions factory. Its return value is a named list of functions.
Then, you can assign the return value to a list and call the member functions when needed.

**Note:** After posting my answer I read [M.Viking's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74322855/8245406)  and it makes sense to return the function's list invisibly. Credits for noticing it go to [@M.Viking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10276092/m-viking).

```r
test_fx <- function() {
  plots_list <- list(
    # Define the first plot
    plot1_fx = function() {
      plot(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(3,4,5), type='l')
      abline(v=1.5, col="red", lwd=5)
    },
    
    # Define the second plot
    plot2_fx = function() {
      plot(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(5,4,3), type='l')
      abline(v=2.5, col="blue", lwd=5)
    }
  )
  # Return the plots
  invisible(plots_list)
}

# Call the main function
p <- test_fx()
p$plot1_fx()
```

[image]

```r
p$plot2_fx()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.

If you use an explicitly define `return()`, you can only return one thing. `multi-argument returns are not permitted`. If you want to return two things, you need to put them inside of something else, like a list:

```
test_fx <- function() {
  
  # Define the first plot
  plot1_fx <- function() {
    plot(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(3,4,5), type='l')
    abline(v=1.5, col="red", lwd=5)
  }
  
  # Define the second plot
  plot2_fx <- function() {
    plot(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(5,4,3), type='l')
    abline(v=2.5, col="blue", lwd=5)
  }
  
  return(invisible(list(plot1_fx(), plot2_fx())))
  
}
test_fx()
```

I added an extra `invisible` call to suppress printing the list.